# Range Hood Pre-Instalation Questions

Tags: wiring, vent, exhaust-fan, ventilation, hood

Is there any way to figure out if my hood vent is circular or rectangular before taking down the old hood?

[Album link](https://imgur.com/a/wf7gToU)

[image]

<sup>New hood (click for fullsize)</sup>

[image]

<sup>New hood (click for fullsize)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Old hood (click for fullsize)</sup>

Happy to post more pictures if it helps. I would just like to make sure everything is compatible before I'm too far in.

Any expertise is valued, thank you!

Comment: You might be able to guess by the cabinetry above, if the vent goes upwards. If it goes into the wall and then up or down, it's probably rectangular. But don't worry: you can get adapters.

Comment: Post up the info tag of your old hood so we can see the model number.  But given that your new hood looks just like a copy of the old one, odds are good the duct is the same 3.25x10 your new one has.

Comment: Here you go. 
https://imgur.com/a/Ebx9EhV